# Boot Ubuntu from Fully Encrypted USB Stick

Tags: boot, usb, encryption

As the title says, I would like to be able to install Ubuntu on a USB stick such that I can (a) boot from the USB stick and (b) Ubuntu uses full disk encryption. I was able to put Ubuntu on a USB stick using Linux Live USB Creator, but it never gives me any install options (install options in the boot menu appear to be for installing Ubuntu on the machine itself, not the USB).

Comment: Full disc encryption does not work with a bootable USB stick. On a persistent drive the OS is part of a squash file that is read only. why encrypt this? Encrypted home directory works with Persistent and Full install flash drives.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive
- boot into one USB stick,
- install Ubuntu into another USB stick (a fast USB 3 stick or SSD connected via USB)
- in the installer's partitioning window, use the option 'LVM with LUKS encrytion'

  [image]

The following link and links from it can help you with details,

- [Step-wise instructions for installed system in a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Answer (score -1):

back up your data before start !
check this link [luks encryptation usb](https://web.archive.org/web/20150505080745/http://ubuntunoob.com/content/encrypt-luks-usb-drive-ubuntu) 
*this was tested with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As I understand your link it adds an encrypted partition to a USB stick, it does not allow for that partition to be bootable, i.e. be where the OS is installed and can start up from after you enter your password.

Comment: i think that depend on where you decide to put the gub, and the live install you have done ..here you have a tuto of how to do a kali live Persistence and encrypted system (http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence)